# density attribute not working for smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I'm having problems with the new smoke and fire features for 2.71. I have followed Jonathon Lampels [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs&list=UUatamfbt5w18LusUifPsIXQ) but it quit working at the part where you put in the attribute node with an attribute of "density". Any idea why it's not working? I also tried the "fire" attribute as well, with no luck.

Here is without connecting the attribute node.

[image]

and here it is with it connected.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `fire` isn't valid, it's `flame`. Not sure why `density` isn't working though.. Could you upload your .blend?

Comment: yea, flame isn't working for me either. How do I upload a blend file?

Comment: Upload it to [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) or whatever host you like and paste the link here.

Comment: @gandalf3 Here it is. I hope this works. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30294

Comment: Your file works fine for me.. Make sure you simulate or bake the smoke before rendering it. You can quickly simulate it by playing the animation with `Alt A`, or you can bake it by pressing *bake* in *Properties > Physics > domain settings > Smoke Cache*.

Comment: hmm. Well it seems to be working. Sorry to bother you!

Comment: Make sure you're using CPU as your render device

Comment: @cegaton The domain would be solid black if OP was using GPU, and there would also be warnings on the nodes. Good guess though..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your smoke has been simulated a bit before you render it.

You can quickly simulate it by playing the animation (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), or you can cache it more permanently by *baking* it (press *Bake* in *Properties > Physics > domain settings > Smoke Cache*).

Once you have done that, you should be able to see the smoke in the viewport and the render.